# How to uninstall inno setup application from Wix bundle

Tags: wix, bundle, inno-setup, uninstallation, bootstrapper

My Wix bundle is installing a few 3rd party EXE packages that are packaged with Inno setup. As you know, Inno Setup uninstaller is a separate executable. Basically, when you install AThirdParty.EXE - it creates an unin000.exe within its deployed folder ( e.g. C:\Program Files (x86)\AThirdPartyApp\unins000.exe ), and that's what I need to execute during my bundle uninstall.. Anyone know how to it with Wix Bootstrapper?

Below is an example of my ExePackage:

```
<PackageGroup Id="MyThirdPartyPackages">
  <ExePackage Id="AThirdPartyExe"
            DisplayName="A Third Party Exe"
            Cache="yes"
            Compressed="yes"
            PerMachine="yes"
            Permanent="no"
            Protocol="none"
            Vital="yes"
            SourceFile=".\AThirdPartyExe.exe"
            DetectCondition="AThirdPartyExeExists"
            InstallCommand="/VERYSILENT /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES"
            UninstallCommand="[ThirtdPartyEXEPath]\unins000.exe" <!-- Can I use uninstallcommand for this?? -->
              />
</PackageGroup>
```

Comment: Does AThirdPartyExe.exe not support /UNINSTALL /VERYSILENT /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES  ?

Comment: No, it does not support AThirdPartyExe.exe /UNINSTALL

Comment: Is there any business justification to just mark this package as permanent and not bother with the uninstall?  (Such as installing .NET or VCRedist.)

Comment: 'permanent' install is the current behavior. I just like to cleanup after myself if possible :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Inno Setup doesn't support an /uninstall flag (no idea but if so yet another reason to only use MSI ) and you don't want to repackage the installer into an MSI the quickest solution I can think of is a man in the middle EXE.

InstallShield used to (may still) have a Helper.exe for some of it's setup prerequisites. You would code it to accept a /INSTALL and /UNINSTALL argument and have WiX call that instead.  It would in turn call the actual install and uninstall as you described above.

Comment: Thanks @Christopher Painter. I was afraid "man in the middle EXE" would be the only option in this case. I don't control the original AThirdPartyExe.exe and can't repackage it as an MSI. So what would the <ExePackage  tag look like? I assume SourceFile=".\ManInTheMiddle.exe" , and InstallCommand=".\AThirdPartyExe.exe /VERYSILENT /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES". Would Wix burn know how to access .\AThirdPartyExe.exe? I mean how would I package it inside my bundle?

Comment: InstallCommand would just be /INSTALL and the MainInTheMiddle would do a process.Start with  AThirdPartyExe.exe /VS /SUP ... .   You'll need to use a Payload element to tell burn to bring the ThirdParty exe along for the ride.

Comment: Inno Setup packages can be uninstalled by default (unless the package has `Uninstallable=yes` configured in the `[Setup]` section). Just run the uninstaller executable (usually, `unins000.exe`). Since you likely want a hands-free uninstall, you would use the `/silent` or `/verysilent` parameter, and probably `/suppressmsgboxes` as well (see the [documentation](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=uninstcmdline) for details).

Comment: @Bill_Stewart the problem is that unins000.exe is a separate executable. By design Wix wants to run the main executable with a command line parameters to uninstall the program

Comment: You can do this using the `AppId` of the installed package and look in the registry for the uninstall command line.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart , but the uninstall command line is using a different executable (unins000.exe). So I don't see how this could work. Assuming you have the uninstall command line, can you provide with an ExePackage tag example? How would you tell Wix bundle to execute that command line? Wix bundle does not support custom actions

Comment: I'm saying have both the InstallCommand and the UninstallCommand call the Helper / MITM EXE.  Then it can call the install exe and the uninstall exe without WiX knowing.